# Checking if a string is valid tag/attribute name for a XML document

Tags: java, xml, regex

**Scenario**

I need to write a validation function that validates XML tag names (or attribute names) .

Eg.:

- `"div"` is valid
- `"d<iv"` is not valid
- `"d\iv"` is not valid

If a string is not valid i should escape that makes it invalid, and replace them with some arbitrary character (or remove it) .

Eg.:

- `"d<iv"` is not valid -> I replace it with `"div"` .

Those functions will be heavily called - so I need to take in consideration code **effectiveness**.

**My problem(s)**

- What are the rules that describe a valid XML tag/attribute name ? Is it safe to consider a valid XML tag/attribute to be described by the same rules as java variable name ? Or are those rules too restrictive ?
- Should I use the java regex package or I should write my own specialized method ? (As I said speed is important) .
- Do you have any suggestions ?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The rules are defined in the xml spec (look at the [name](http://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#NT-Name) definition)

If speed matters, then don't use regular expressions. Do it more like this:

```
public static String correctName(String name) {
  StringBuilder nameBuilder = new StringBuilder();
  for (char nameChar:name.charArray())
     if (isValidXml(nameChar))          // some magic left to do ;)
         nameBuilder.append(nameChar);
  return nameBuilder.toString();
}
```

Note - the code above is a simple guideline, it does not cover the little annoyance, that the first char of an xml name has a different value range ... if you want to correct illegal tags like `$%&div` then it's a bit more complicated (more magic needed)